# require() in a runtime but it runs only once. Is it ok?

Tags: javascript, node.js, config

I have many configs in their directories which are responding for different tasks. But in some cases i need to get a config from another file. Example:

File1:

```
module.exports = Object.freeze({
  uid: 'uid',
  name: 'name',
  admin: 'admin',
  balance: 'balance',
  state: 'state',
  bet: 'bet',
  size: 'size',
  chance: 'chance',
  language: 'language'
})
```

File2:

```
module.exports = Object.freeze({
  url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/',
  table: 'casino-db',
  row: 'users',
  user: require('/api/user/config')
})
```

Is it ok? I've heard that dynamic call of `require()` is bad, because of it works another way rather than calling it from a file start.

Does someone uses that config structure?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that, it will only be evaluated once. All calls to `require()` work the same way and in fact it has an internal cache to prevent a dependency from running more than once anyway, so subsequent calls are basically reduced to a property access on a cache object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subsequent require calls get cached under require.cache object.
What you are doing is okay because you re exporting just an object. So it doesn't get re-calculated after many requires.

If you are worried about it, you can just do this:

```
const user = require('/api/user/config')
module.exports = Object.freeze({
  url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/',
  table: 'casino-db',
  row: 'users',
  user
})
```

Comment: This is wrong. exports don't get re-executed. Nothing in the top level of a module gets re-executed.

Comment: Your answer implies `module.exports` gets re-executed. It doesn't. `Only if you clear require's cache, it can get re-processed` is still wrong.

Comment: I just checked, the entire module gets re-processed if you clear the require cache.

placed a console.log in the file, out of the module.exports and it gets re-called after clearing the cache and requiring the module again

Comment: The "it" in "it can get re-processed" is referring to the `module.exports = ...`, not the `require()` itself. There are 3 different files here. The file `/api/user/config.js`, the one `require()`ing that, and exporting another object, and the third file not shown, requiring that. If you clear `/api/user/config.js` from the cache, the code `module.exports = ...` does _not_ get re-executed is what I'm saying.

Comment: But in practice, that cache will never be cleared anyway, so that's not something to worry about in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with dynamic calling to `require()`. As per the docs, all requires are cached.

Answer (score 0):

is file1 dependent on file2?

if not, why can't you just...

```
// file 1
module.exports = Object.freeze({
  uid: 'uid',
  name: 'name',
  admin: 'admin',
  balance: 'balance',
  state: 'state',
  bet: 'bet',
  size: 'size',
  chance: 'chance',
  language: 'language'
})

// file2
module.exports = Object.freeze({
  url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/',
  table: 'casino-db',
  row: 'users'
})

// some index.js
module.exports = {
  file1: require('./file1'),
  file2: require('./file2')
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). It's gonna be more easy :))

Comment: please just posting something is not quality of answering